# SQL Server counting unrelated conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, conditional-statements

Folks,

I have researched this question first and came up with nothing for my specific issue, I found `SUM/CASE` which is neat but not exactly what I need. Here is my situation:

I have been asked to report back the total number of people who meet **5 out of 8 conditions**.
I am having trouble coming up with the best way of doing this. It must be something to do with having a `counter` for each condition and then adding the counter at the end and returning the count of people who met 5 of the 8 conditions (call them condition a - h)

So can you do a count of a count?

Something like

```
if exists (code for condition A) 1 ELSE 0 
if exists (code for condition B) 1 ELSE 0 
etc

sum(count)
```

Thank you

Comment: To help you we need more details about your schema and what you have tried until now. Also, what database you ware working with?

Comment: Are the conditions all present on the same row, or do multiple rows need to be analyzed?

Comment: I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2 ,multiple rows and tables need to be analyzed for this

Comment: Please provide a representative sample of such conditions.

Comment: Answer to your general question "*can you do a count of a count?*" is "Yes". You will need to use `sub-queries` and/or `JOIN`s.

Comment: "Exactly" 5 out of 8 or "at least" 5 out of 8?

Comment: @rwking at least 5 out of 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up completing this by using a WITH statement
something like this:

WITH

(

Select statement for first condition AS blah

Select statement for second condition AS blah

Select statement for third condition AS blah

Select statement for fourth condition AS blah

Select statement for fifth condition AS blah

Select statement for sixth condition AS blah

Select statement for seventh condition AS blah

Select statement for eighth condition AS blah

)

select

CASE WHEN (8 cases based on the 8 selects above

I just put the results in a spreadsheet and did all the math in Excel

Answer (score 1):

Since the conditions are spread across rows, you can do this by combining `MAX()` and a `CASE` statement in a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT person_ID
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Person_ID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN ConditionA THEN 1 END)
     + MAX(CASE WHEN ConditionB THEN 1 END)
     + MAX(CASE WHEN ConditionC THEN 1 END)
     + MAX(CASE WHEN ConditionD THEN 1 END)
     + MAX(CASE WHEN ConditionE THEN 1 END)
     + MAX(CASE WHEN ConditionF THEN 1 END)
     + MAX(CASE WHEN ConditionG THEN 1 END)
     + MAX(CASE WHEN ConditionH THEN 1 END)
    >= 5
```

Comment: As below, should be >=5

Comment: @rwking perhaps, but the OP states "people who meet 5 out of 8 conditions" not 'at least 5'.

Comment: True. This might be incorrect, but I almost think that someone who meets 6 out of 8 conditions also meets 5 out of 8 conditions.

Comment: So sorry, correct at least 5 conditions, my mistake so >= 5 is correct in this case

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN (Code for condition A) then 1 else 0 end + 
      CASE WHEN (Code for condition B) then 1 else 0 end +
      CASE WHEN (Code for condition C) then 1 else 0 end +
      ...
      = 5
```

Comment: I think the condition should be more like >= 5.

Answer (score 0):

User defined function to the rescue

```
SELECT * FROM view_people_with_conditions_count WHERE conditions_count  BETWEEN 5 AND 8

CREATE VIEW view_people_with_conditions_count
AS
SELECT *, dbo.GetCondtionsCount(id) as conditions_count FROM peoples_table

CREATE function GetCondtionsCount(@id int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @counter int

      ' implement your conditions here
      IF (condtion1) SET @counter = @counter + 1
      IF (condtion2) SET @counter = @counter + 1
      IF (condtion3) SET @counter = @counter + 1
      RETURN @counter
END
```